# Sending emails by CRON every minute - can my method be improved?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, cron

I'm working on a reminder type of site, where you can set reminders to be sent to yourself, set a time for the reminders, and when the time occurs, you'll be sent an email.

However, the reminders aren't critical, and a delay of around 5-10 minutes is acceptable.

I have two options:

1) Run a cron script every minute. The script will check if there are any events in the db scheduled for CURTIME() , (i.e if the cron is run at 5:35:30 it will check for any reminders set at 5:35:00). If not found, terminate. If found, send the emails out.

2) Or, I can run a Cron script every 10 minutes. This script will check if there are any reminders scheduled between now and 10 minutes ago. E.g if cron is run at 5:35:30, it will check for any reminders between 5:25:00 and 5:35:00. If found, send them, if not, terminate.

The only issue I have with the 2nd method, is I'm not positive if this will not cause some reminders to not get sent out.

E.g what if the server was under higher load, and a Cron scheduled for 5:35:00 instead runs at 5:37:00. Then any emails scheduled for 5:35:00 might be missed.

Which method should I go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same option, differing only in period.

You might think of this as an intervalic poll or queue sweep, but "non-real-time," and so you must design for lag.

Generally, every sweep should assume it might have been delayed, and further the system should have some defined policy for dealing with queued notifications that are "too old."  (What if the system is powered off for an hour before it can sweep newly enqueued notifications?)

For robustness, ensure that queue processing is atomic or synchronized — no double-processing of items whether from concurrent sweeps or subsequent sweeps.

Comment: How much lag should I design for? I.e if the crons are scheduled to be run every 10 mins, should i check for anything upto 15 mins old? As for the reminders being too old, I've designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

on Windows and Unix machines, there's `at`, which is used to schedule one-shot jobs at specified times. Unless you're sending so many emails that it makes more sense to check/send every minute, it'd probably be easier to simply have the "save my reminder" code schedule the sending via an `at` job instead.

Comment: Thanks for this! Question, can this be scheduled via PHP?

Comment: yes, basically `exec('at ...')`, though you'll have to make sure that your webserver's UID has rights/access to the scheduler